# replace function with parameters as string array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, replace

well ,I have text file contain these string `666 66 55 333 55` for example and I have two arrays of string one of them contains the string in text file without repetitions and the other values from 1 to array1 size I need to replace each string in text file for example if `array1 = {666,66,333,55}`  `array2` will be `{1,2,3,4}`   text file should be like that `(1 2 4 3 4 )` i try this code the problem with it is replace `66` by `1` and `666` become `16` ,so it consider `66` as part of `666` I need away to get over-this,it good to know that this code work in other cases I mean `55` in text file become `4` and `333` become `3`.

```
      stra() as string={666,66,333,55}
       stra2()as string={1,2,3,4}
    For j = 0 To stra.GetLength(0)

        Const ForReading = 1
        Const ForWriting = 2

        Dim objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, ForReading)

        Dim strText = objFile.ReadAll

        objFile.Close()
        Dim strNewText = Regex.Replace(strText, stra(j), stra2(j))

        objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, ForWriting)
        objFile.WriteLine(strNewText)
        objFile.Close()
    Next
```

Comment: Is this vb.net? why are you using `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`?

Comment: yeah ,vb.net,but I have no problem with reading and writing on file ,I can change it but the result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

Create the following function:

```
Function Process(items As String()) As Integer()
    Dim dictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    Dim result = New List(Of Integer)

    For i = 0 To items.Length - 1
        Dim item = items(i)

        If Not (dictionary.ContainsKey(item)) Then
            Dim value = dictionary.Count + 1

            dictionary.Add(item, value)
            result.Add(value)
        Else
            result.Add(dictionary(item))
        End If
    Next

    Return result.ToArray()

End Function
```

This function takes an array of strings as input, and returns an array of integers as output.

It uses a `Dictionary` to store the index of the first occurrence of the string.

It uses this dictionary to detect if the item has already appeared before, and if it did, it uses the original index.

You can consume this function like this:

```
Dim input_file = "c:\\input.txt"
Dim output_file = "c:\\output.txt"

Dim input = File.ReadAllText(input_file)

Dim items = input.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim output_items = Process(items)

Dim string_output_items = output_items.Select(Function(item) item.ToString()).ToArray()

Dim output = String.Join(" ", string_output_items)

File.WriteAllText(output_file, output)
```

**UPDATE**:

If your input file contains lines and you want to keep such structure, then use the following code:

```
Dim input_file = "c:\\input.txt"
Dim output_file = "c:\\output.txt"

Dim input_lines = File.ReadAllLines(input_file)

Dim number_list = New List(Of String)
Dim numbers_per_line_list = New List(Of Integer)

For Each input_line As String In input_lines
    Dim numbers = input_line.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    number_list.AddRange(numbers)
    numbers_per_line_list.Add(numbers.Length)
Next


Dim output_numbers = Process(number_list.ToArray())

Dim string_output_numbers = output_numbers.Select(Function(item) item.ToString()).ToList()


Dim output_lines = New List(Of String)

For Each numbers_in_line As Integer In numbers_per_line_list

    Dim numbers_for_this_line = string_output_numbers.GetRange(0, numbers_in_line)

    string_output_numbers.RemoveRange(0, numbers_in_line)

    Dim line = String.Join(" ", numbers_for_this_line)

    output_lines.Add(line)
Next

File.WriteAllLines(output_file, output_lines)
```

This code reads lines instead of reading the whole file as a single string. And for each line, it stores the number of items in the line. When it writes the results to the file, it uses theses information to output the correct number of items to each line.

Comment: Than'ks Yacoub ,I try the code in my input file 3 appears three times in different position in output file in1 position replaces by 5 and in other two position 3 appears as 8 it suppose to be 5 again

Comment: @rasha, can you show your input file? does it contain new lines?

Comment: ok,this is my input file   2 6 4 81 
                                    3 4 6 77 
                                    1 3 3 55 7

Comment: actually ,I'm working with data set  so it contain new lines

Comment: Since your input file contains lines, you need to consider new lines as seperators, replace `Dim items = input.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` with `Dim items = input.Split(New String() {" ", Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: big thank's to you  it work like a charm ..Is there any way to make output file  have the same order as input file